# Django Test Not Getting Model Object

Tags: python, django, testing, heroku, django-models

I am just scratching the surface of testing in Django.  Here is my testing code, inside `tests.py`:

```
class AdvertisingTests( TestCase ):

    def test_get_ad( self ):
        '''
        Test if the get ad feature is working, should always load an ad
        '''
        url = reverse('advertising:get_ad')
        response = self.client.get( url )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

This test is just a basic test of a view that should return an Ad.  Here is the view code:

```
from .models import Ad, Impression

def get_ad(request):
    FirstAd = Ad.objects.first()

    # +1 impression
    Impression.objects.create(ad = FirstAd)

    import json
    data = { 'url': FirstAd.url, 'image_url': FirstAd.image.url, 'title': FirstAd.title, 'desc': FirstAd.desc }
    json_data = json.dumps( data )
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

I am working in a heroku local environment, so I run the tests like this:
`heroku local:run python manage.py test advertising`

And this test fails, coming from the `Impression.objects.create(ad = FirstAd)` line:

> ValueError: Cannot assign None: "Impression.ad" does not allow null
>   values.

What that tells me is that the `FirstAd` object is null.  OK so I wind up the local shell like this: `heroku local:run python manage.py shell` to double check.  Replicating that code there are no errors:

```
In [2]: from advertising.models import Ad, Impression

In [3]: print Ad.objects.first()
Flamingo T-Shirt Corporation

In [4]: FirstAd = Ad.objects.first()

In [5]: Impression.objects.create(ad = FirstAd)
Out[5]: <Impression: Impression object>

In [6]: exit()
```

So I am a little bit stuck.  It seems like the tester is accessing an empty database.  Is this the correct and desired functionality of the testing suite?

THANKS!

**UPDATE**

OK so all this is normal, I should have known that.  Adding the setUp function to my test class to initialise data is what I needed to do.  Like this:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

def setUp(self):
    test_user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='12345')

    this_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    banner_image = os.path.join(this_path, "static/advertising/images/pic01.jpg")
    mobile_image = os.path.join(this_path, "static/advertising/images/pic02.jpg")

    Ad.objects.create(
        title = "Test Title",
        desc = "Test Description",
        image = SimpleUploadedFile(name='test_image.jpg', content=open(banner_image, 'rb').read(), content_type='image/jpeg'),
        mobile_image = SimpleUploadedFile(name='test_image.jpg', content=open(mobile_image, 'rb').read(), content_type='image/jpeg'),
        url = "https://www.jefferythewind.com",
        user = test_user
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django tests create empty temporaty database see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-data), which will be destroyed after tests.

To prepopulate testing DB with data you can use [`setUp`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests) method:

```
class AdvertisingTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Ad.objects.create(name="myAd")
```

Also you can use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading).