# Script executes perfectly, so why does the unittest throw an IndexError?

Tags: python

I am currently writing some tests for a python script. The script runs exactly as I expect it to with no issues. 
The issue I am having is that when I call one function from my unit test, I get an: IndexError: list index out of range message.

For the unittest shown below, I followed [this](https://www.expobrain.net/2013/08/27/mocking-objects-in-unit-tests/) example.

I have not been able to find a similar issue through Googling, so I'm not sure where to even start. If I print the item from my script, it prints the value I expect.

```
def build_message(self, {some other into}):
    # Get email templates
    template = Templates.objects.filter(template_id=1)
    # This next line is what gives me the error.
    fields = template[0]
```

I am calling it in a unittest like this:

```
def test_send_email(self):
    # Mock 'smtplib.SMTP' class
    with patch("smtplib.SMTP") as mock_smtp:
        # Build test message
        to_address = "email@address
        # Build message
        msg = handle_command.build_message(self, {some other info})
```

The error I am getting is this. I do not understand why here is says index out of range, when running my script works perfectly fine.

```
    fields = template[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 307, in __getitem__
    return qs._result_cache[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541523/django-test-not-getting-model-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is either no data at all, or at least no data with template_id = 1 in your table. See this test I just ran that produces the same error (the line number is actually different but maybe we are running different versions of Django).

```
>>> from cato.models import *
>>> Menu.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> m = Menu.objects.filter(id=1)
>>> len(m)
0
>>> m[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\csullivan\responsive\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 291, in __getitem__
    return self._result_cache[k]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

You can see I import my models, and get all objects from the Menu model. There is none as it returns an empty queryset. Then I use the filter on id=1 which is successful, but also returns an empty queryset, which of course has length zero. Then if I try to access element 0, which doesn't exist, I get an identical error.

Don't forget that Django TestCase creates a fresh set of empty database tables and it is up to you to fill them either with queries or more commonly with fixtures.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense. I somehow forgot that Django TestCase creates empty tables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is sorting out how, when a test is running

```
template = Templates.objects.filter(template_id=1)
```

is returning an empty set. This is what you'll see if the test class doesn't cause `Templates` to get populated.